Upload image with PUT does not work in Production (digital ocean) - Laravel and vue
I have a weird problem: Uploading a image in local WORKS perfectly but when I upload to Production in digital ocean it does NOT.
Iam using laravel 11, vue 3 and InertiaJS
What happens in Production its that a zero 0 value its stored instead the usual path and the image does not. Another weird thing its that I have another form with POST method which already works on production. I tried to change this form to POST but still failing.
How front works: A button opens a modal and that action select a player who owns a photo. The player data its filled in the form and the input file allows to select new photo which its included in the Inertia JS form. In the useForm I include the _method: 'PUT' because PHP has problemas sending files directly with PUT method and laravel allows override the POST method form.

When The modal its opened by method @click="openUpdatePlayer(user)"the field photo its filled with the current photo formPlayer.photo = player.photo;

FILE Field
<TextInput
                    id="photo"
                    name="photo"
                    type="file"
                    placeholder = "Foto del jugador"
                    class="mt-1 block w-full border-gray-300 dark:border-gray-700 dark:bg-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-500 dark:focus:border-indigo-600 focus:ring-indigo-500 dark:focus:ring-indigo-600 rounded-md shadow-sm"
                    @input="formPlayer.photo = $event.target.files[0]"
                />
<PrimaryButton
                    class="ms-3"
                    :class="{ 'opacity-25': formPlayer.processing }"
                    :disabled="formPlayer.processing"
                    @click="updatePlayer()"
                >
                    Actualizar
                </PrimaryButton>

Form player
const formPlayer = useForm({ //I let just some fields for visualization purposes  
weight: 0,
height: 0,
email: null,
photo: null,
_method: 'PUT'

});
Form code
const updatePlayer = () => {
formPlayer.post(route('playerUpdate', formPlayer.id), {
    //onFinish: () => formPlayer.reset(),
    onSuccess: () => closePlayerModal(),
});

};
CONTROLLER CODE
if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {
        $image = $request->file('photo')->store('photos', 'public');
        $user->photo = $image;
    } else {
        dd('error uploading photo', $request->file('photo'));
    }


With 30 seconds of debugging you could narrow this down a lot. Is the file being uploaded? If so, it's a server-side problem and nothing to do with Vue or Inertia

Hello @miken32 , The file its not arriving to the server. Instead its getting stored a zero in BD. In fact. Its not for permissions because In other form I stored files but this form does not work. The difference is the _method PUT. Any ideas ?

I already fixed. There was permission in the directory storage. By mistake I uploaded a default image with the photos directory. I causes the user owns the directory and not the www-data. Thats did not notice.
Learnings:

Uploading and image with POST and laravel works
To uploaded with PUT method you have to use _method = PUT in the use form Js
Always check permissions and the storage method for files in laravel
Inertia injects automaticaly the form multipart

Have a good luck
